# Vim functions for cleaning up hidden characters

Tags: vim

Currently in my .vimrc file I have a function which clears all trailing white spaces on save, while retaining my mouse position.

```
fun! <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
  let l = line(".")
  let c = col(".")
  %s/\s\+$//e
  call cursor(l, c)
endfun

autocmd BufWritePre *.sql,*.php :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
```

This works great. But I would like to add a few more things to it like:
* Remove carriage returns
* Fix indent SP followed by a TAB

I tried adding

> %s/^M//e

to my `StripTailingWhitespaces()` function, but when I save now vim tells me

> Press ENTER or type command to continue

So I think I did something wrong or am forgetting something. Any help figuring this out? Thanks

**UPDATE:** Still working on this problem. I've tried adding a `<CR>` at the end of my searches in the `StripTrailingWhitespaces` function as well as at the end of the `BufWritePre` command. No luck. In fact, adding it gives me lots of "Trailing Spaces" errors. Any more suggestions?

If not one for fixing the need to press enter problem, what about a search to fix indent SP followed by a TAB?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it with

```
fun! S()
  let l = line(".")
  let c = col(".")
  %s/\s\+$//e
  %s/^M//e   
  call cursor(l, c)
endfun
```

and it worked perfectly with Vim 7.3 (Note: the ^M is entered with CTRL-V CTRL-M)

So, it looks like you don't do anything wrong, and haven't forgotten anything.

Now, that doesn't help you going further, does it?

If you have this message, try `:messages`, maybe this will give you a hint.

Also, `:help messages` reads

```
  Press ENTER or type command to continue

This message is given when there is something on the screen for you to read,
and the screen is about to be redrawn:
- After executing an external command (e.g., ":!ls" and "=").
- Something is displayed on the status line that is longer than the width of
  the window, or runs into the 'showcmd' or 'ruler' output.
```

So, this section might be worth reading (it's longer than the one I pasted).

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm on vim 7.1.138. Is that possibly the issue?

Comment: I doubt that (although I am not 100% sure)